# Date in database changes to the current date

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I am saving the data with the date it was filed, but the date I inset changes to the current date

When you save the data

```
Calendar currentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
DB.putInformation(DB, done_today1 + "\n" + done_today2 + "\n" + done_today3, thankful_for1 + "\n" + thankful_for2 + "\n" + thankful_for3 + "\n" + thankful_for4 + "\n" + thankful_for5, for_relationship, for_kids, for_business, currentDate.get(Calendar.DATE) + "-" + currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Inserts the data into the table

```
public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop,String happenedToday,String thankfulFor,String forRelationship,String forKids,String forBusiness,String currentDate){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ=dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.DONE_TODAY, happenedToday);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.THANKFUL_FOR,thankfulFor);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.FOR_RELATIONSHIP,forRelationship);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.FOR_KIDS,forKids);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.FOR_BUSINESS,forBusiness);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.CURRENT_DATE,currentDate);
    SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.d("Database operations", "One Row Inserted");
```

And when I retrieve the date this way

```
Cursor CR = dop.getInformation(dop);
CR.moveToFirst();
Toast.makeText(DisplayTable.this,""+CR.getString(5),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I am getting the current date and not the date that the data was filed in.

Any one knows why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `CURRENT_DATE` is a keyword that refers to the current date.

To access a column with the same name, you have to quote the column name (double quotes are for identifiers; single quotes are for strings):

```
> CREATE TABLE t(current_date);
> INSERT INTO t VALUES('x');
> SELECT current_date FROM t;
2015-09-28
> SELECT "current_date" FROM t;
x
> SELECT 'current_date' FROM t;
current_date
```

It might be a better idea to use a different column name.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to handle date and times is to always use ISO standard timestamps, the ones with T and Z. This makes translating actual dates within different time zones easy.

One way also is saving date and times using unix timestamp, its a long integer that can be translated to the actual dates of different time zones, so it will reflect always the correct time based on your time zone.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't really solve the problem,
you see, the problem is that the date in the database changes every day to the current date.
for example if I filed the data today, the date will be 28-9-2015.
tomorrow the date should be 28-9-2015, but instead its 29-9-2015.

Why is that happening?